# Java Spark with MYSQL connection

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and integrating my existing application with Spark. 
How do I connect to mysql using Spark Java.

Currently I am run

```
<pre>
Map<String, String> options1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            options1.put("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=root&password=password");
            options1.put("dbtable",
                    "test_table ");
//          Dataset<Row> dataFrameReader1 = session.read().format("jdbc").options(options1).load().cache();
```

Now I have to integrate in my existing application with connection object.

Could you please help?

Comment: What do you mean _Now I have to integrate in my existing application with connection object._ ?

Comment: Never do `cache()` right after loading data from source. Instead write data to to file system if you don't want to connect to MySQL again and again.

Comment: @mrsrinivas how to use it in application where i have datasource and connection pooling.Do i have to pass option every time my app interact with DB?

Comment: **connection pooling** happens at application server layer, so it's out of scope with respect to Spark. **Spark Executors will establish connections with database and reads their partition of data from DB using the connection string we provided**.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So If i have 3 query do i have to pass connection string 3 times ?

Comment: AFAIK Yes! As you already build `options` object, you need to pass 3 times to create dataframes from tables.